# i got ZeroDivisionError in scipy.minimize function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I have two columned Pandas Series (DataTime and Float) and i try make timeseries analys.
I use  scipy.minimize as an example (https://medium.com/open-machine-learning-course/open-machine-learning-course-topic-9-time-series-analysis-in-python-a270cb05e0b3), but got

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I compare my datasets and datasets in example, and structurally both examples has identical (two columns, first - DateTime, second - Data on float or integer).

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

def timeseriesCVscore(x):
    # errors vector
    errors = []

    values = data.values
    alpha, beta, gamma = x

    # set cross-validation folds value
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3) 

    # check fold, learn model, try to build forecast and got errors
    for train, test in tscv.split(values):

        model = HoltWinters(series=values[train], slen = 24*7, alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n_preds=len(test))
        model.triple_exponential_smoothing()

        predictions = model.result[-len(test):]
        actual = values[test]
        error = mean_squared_error(predictions, actual)
        errors.append(error)

    # Returning the mean square of the error over the error vector
    return np.mean(np.array(errors))
```

This function work correctly. But if i try:

```
data = data[:-20] # leave some data for testing

# initializing model parameters alpha, beta and gamma
x = [0, 0, 0] 

# Minimizing the loss function 
opt = minimize(timeseriesCVscore, x0=x, 
               args=(data, mean_squared_log_error), 
               method="TNC", bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
              )

# Take optimal values...
alpha_final, beta_final, gamma_final = opt.x
print(alpha_final, beta_final, gamma_final)

# ...and train the model with them, forecasting for the next 50 hours
model = HoltWinters(data, slen = 24, 
                    alpha = alpha_final, 
                    beta = beta_final, 
                    gamma = gamma_final, 
                    n_preds = 50, scaling_factor = 3)
model.triple_exponential_smoothing()
```

I have ZeroDivionError, i try change data slice, change bounds values on two, delete gamma in function, but nothing

Errors log:

```
ZeroDivisionError Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    620                                 callback=callback, **options)
    621     elif meth == 'tnc':
--> 622         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,
    623                              **options)
    624     elif meth == 'cobyla':

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\tnc.py in _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, eps, scale, offset, mesg_num, maxCGit, maxiter, eta, stepmx, accuracy, minfev, ftol, xtol, gtol, rescale, disp, callback, finite_diff_rel_step, maxfun, **unknown_options)
    373         messages = MSG_NONE
    374 
--> 375     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
    376                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step,
    377                                   bounds=new_bounds)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    259     # ScalarFunction caches. Reuse of fun(x) during grad
    260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
--> 261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
    262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    263 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
    134 
    135         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun
--> 136         self._update_fun()
    137 
    138         # Gradient evaluation

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in _update_fun(self)
    224     def _update_fun(self):
    225         if not self.f_updated:
--> 226             self._update_fun_impl()
    227             self.f_updated = True
    228 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in update_fun()
    131 
    132         def update_fun():
--> 133             self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
    134 
    135         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in fun_wrapped(x)
    128         def fun_wrapped(x):
    129             self.nfev += 1
--> 130             return fun(x, *args)
    131 
    132         def update_fun():

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5692/3490566462.py in timeseriesCVscore(x)
     15 
     16         model = HoltWinters(series=values[train], slen = 24*7, alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n_preds=len(test))
---> 17         model.triple_exponential_smoothing()
     18 
     19         predictions = model.result[-len(test):]

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5692/1780047143.py in triple_exponential_smoothing(self)
     54         self.LowerBond = []
     55 
---> 56         seasonals = self.initial_seasonal_components()
     57 
     58         for i in range(len(self.series)+self.n_preds):

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5692/1780047143.py in initial_seasonal_components(self)
     41             for j in range(n_seasons):
     42                 sum_of_vals_over_avg += self.series[self.slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
---> 43             seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons
     44         return seasonals
     45 

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: I edit post and add traceback

Comment: Still not the full trace - it is not clear *where exactly* in your code the error has occurred. Is it on `minimize`? If yes, please **remove** any code that comes after it.

Comment: your normalisation `sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons` does not work when n_seasons is `0`. In this case the for loop `for j in range(n_seasons):` is not executed at all, but in the end you divide by 0.